# How do I run multiple instances of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

How do I run multiple instances of Android Studio?  A second instance is launched if you select "File\New Project", but "File\Open" and "File\Reopen" does not create a second instance.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Your Android Studio was set to open project in the same window. You can change that, so it asks whether to open new window while opening other project.

**Do this:**

1. Go to: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project Opening.
2. Check [x] "Confirm window to open project in".
3. Now open the other (2nd) project with File -> Open... etc.
4. You will now be asked if you want to open a new window or replace what you already have. Select New Window.

---

**Screenshots:**

[image: settings]

[image: what to open]

---

**Older versions:**

1. Go to Settings -> General -> Project opening.
2. Check 'Confirm window to open project in'.
3. Create or open different project
4. You will be asked if open a new window.

[image]

Comment: under OSX, it's under 'Android Studio' > 'Preferences' menu (CMD+,)

Comment: File -> Settings or Ctrl-Alt-S by default to open settings.

Comment: I found this under Apperance &Behavior > System Settings

Comment: But how do I run two different file image (.app in mac) Android Studio. I want to have one stable and one canary?

Comment: Once the above mentioned setting is adjusted, go to file and locate the project that you want to open, Android studio will prompt you about opening the project in new window or same window. Select new window to open the project in a new instance.

Comment: You just saved my day. Every clue was pointing to how to open multiple projects in the same instance..

Comment: this does not work anymore, nothing happens when I try to open again the same project

Comment: This answer is misleading: opening project in new window does not spawn new instance of Android Studio. Unless these projects are trivial this almost always causes Android Studio to immediately hit memory consumption limits (if it hasn't already).

Comment: This option doesn't exist in the latest version (2023) version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

There was an update in Android studio so the new solution would be:

1. go to >file
2. go to >settings
3. go to >appearance and behavior
4. go to > system settings
5. now in system settings check the **"confirm to open project in"** option

Comment: Why this answer is not accepted instead of Grzegorz's answer which is posted on  Aug 18 '13?

Answer (score 3):

On Mac is:

1. Android Studio
2. Preferences
3. Appearance & Behavior
4. System Settings -> Project Opening -> Confirm to open project in

When you open other project, you will be asked if you want to open a new window or replace what you already have.

Comment: Shortcut - `⌘`+ `,`

Answer (score 1):

The setting to allow multiple instances as of Android Studio 2022.2.1:

[image]

Select either `New window` or `Ask`.