# How do I open two or more projects at the same time in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, I want to open another project, so I click File -> Open, but the original project has been closed.

What should I do to open the two projects at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Studio How to open multiple project in single window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646114/android-studio-how-to-open-multiple-project-in-single-window)

Comment: Thanks, my question is little different and I have solved it.

Comment: This sound like a duplicate of [How do I run multiple instances of Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299698/how-do-i-run-multiple-instances-of-android-studio).

Answer (score 47):

To open multiple projects simultaneously in Android Studio,
go to **Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings**,
in the **Project Opening** section,
choose **Open project in new window**.

[image: Screenshot for Settings in Android Studio]

Answer (score 8):

Umh,I have solved my question.
First,I try to click the File->Find Action and search 'open new project'.Then I find a result and enter the settings window:Project opening.(So sad I have no reputation to post a picture)
Select the first check box.

Answer (score 0):

Simple if your MAC user

Goto **Window** from top **toolbar**

then see **Merge all project window** click on it your good to go

attached image for ref.

[image]