# How do I run two instances of Android Studio with different preferences e.g. different SDK locations, different gradle versions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I happen to have two projects running on my Mac, A and B, where I need to compile A into B and then run B to see the changes. However, B uses a different SDK path from and uses a custom gradle, so I cannot open two Android Studio windows without the preferences conflicting.

I'm currently just coding on A while using the settings on B, and compiling via terminal, but I don't get to see the layouts since the custom gradle won't run correctly on A and won't render them.

Anyone has a workaround to this?

Comment: Try to do it with 2 differents version of android studio

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302823/936293

Answer (score 0):

To change the sdk location in *Android Studio* :
`File -> Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) -> SDK Location`
Then change the *Android SDK Location*
To change the gradle version in *Android Studio* :

1. **Open the `build.gradle` file of the project**
2. **Go to `dependencies -> classpath`**
3. **Change the *gradle version***
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXrT7.png)