# How to have two independent Android Studio instances?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with 2 monitors. Let the left monitor show a project I forked from someone as a reference. As I am trying to understand the forked project, I create a new project on the right monitor.

During my learning, I need to access the contents of the forked project while I am writing on my own project. For example, when I open `New Android Activity` modal dialog window on the right monitor, I cannot access  the open Android Studio on the left monitor to know the name of the activity, etc.

Is there any method to make both Android Studio instance independent? Opening modal dialog window on one instance will not prevent us from accessing the other instance.

Comment: Don't suggest me to either read the forked project on github or use two computers. :-) I don't understand why Android Studio must be singleton.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run multiple instances of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299698/how-do-i-run-multiple-instances-of-android-studio)

Comment: @IulianPopescu: No. Because the modal dialog box issue still exists. The instances are not independent.

Comment: I don't know what to say here, but to be frank, it looks like nitpicking.  You could file a bug for the Android Studio team, but I would not bet my money on having it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jetbrains Toolbox https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/ to install two completely separate instances of Android Studio. Probably not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Sorry, how to open two instances of Android Studio after installing the Jetbrain's toolbox and reinstalling another Android Studio? I have now two Android Studio installed but I have no idea to run two instances. I have renamed them as `Android Studio 1` and `Android Studio 2`.